# TYPO3 9.5.0 - pageUid of f:link.page not reading t3://page?uid=80

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 9.5.0LTS and use the bootstrap package theme. It seems to be all working ... except ... when I add a link (internal or external) to a carousel item ... nothing gets rendered. The other elements come out fine.

I looked in the CalltoAction.html ... and found out that pageUid of f:link.page is not reading t3://page?uid=80.

When I {records} ... I get link => 't3://page?uid=80' (16 chars)

And when I test in CalltoAction.html:

```
<p>{item.data.link}</p>
<f:if condition="{item.data.link}">
    <f:link.page pageUid="1" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary" additionalAttributes="{draggable:'false'}">
        <f:if condition="{item.data.button_text}">
            <f:then>
                <span>{item.data.button_text}</span>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <span><f:translate key="readmore" extensionName="bootstrap_package" /></span>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </f:link.page>
</f:if>
<f:if condition="{item.data.link}">
    <f:link.page pageUid="{item.data.link}" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary" additionalAttributes="{draggable:'false'}">
        <f:if condition="{item.data.button_text}">
            <f:then>
                <span>{item.data.button_text}</span>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <span><f:translate key="readmore" extensionName="bootstrap_package" /></span>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </f:link.page>
</f:if>
```

I get the following result in the FE:

```
<p>t3://page?uid=80</p>
<a draggable="false" class="carousel-item-button btn btn-primary" href="/"><span>Read more</span></a>
<span>Read more</span>
```

So pageUid of f:link.page not reading t3://page?uid=80

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `f:link.page`-VH expects an integer (`uid`) in the parameter `pageUid`.

`t3://page?uid=80` by way is no integer but a string. A special string which can be handled by the `f:link.typo3link`-VH

Comment: I don't find any documentation on how to work with this vh?! Do you have a link?

Comment: oops, typo in name of VH, https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Link/TypolinkViewHelper.html or https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Typolink.html